# Argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, qgis, parcel

There are code for QGIS which used for parcel evaluation.

```
  import processing
processing.run('qgis:postgisexecutesql', "parcell_GIS07", "select_parcel_eval('[%"cadnum" %]')")
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

When i try to use it on parcel in QGIS, it give off error window with this code:

```
An error occurred during execution of following code:
import processing 
processing.run('qgis:postgisexecutesql', "parcell_GIS07", "select_parcel_eval('060130018')") 
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 106, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 133, in runAlgorithm
    ok, msg = alg.checkParameterValues(parameters, context)
TypeError: QgsProcessingAlgorithm.checkParameterValues(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Comment: Whatever code you've shown isn't quite what you're running. Specifically because this part will give an invalid syntax error: `"select_parcel_eval('[%"cadnum" %]')"`

Comment: also processing.run expects two arguments:: one string and one dict. You have given it 3 strings. https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html

Comment: You might be looking for `processing.runalg()` https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database/postgisexecutesql.html

Comment: @JeffUK runalg is for previous version of QGIS